# How to count number of rows containing exactly one NaN (XOR operation) on a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas

In the table below, I would return `2`, by the sum of the rows with indices `2` and `3`.

```
0   NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN
2   Apple   NaN
3   NaN     Mango
4   Banana  Grape
```

To elaborate, row `2` contains one non-NaN element, so for a variable tracking the count, `count += 1` when we iterate through each row and encounter row `2`. Similarly, for row `3`, we would have `count += 1`, leading to the count being a total of 2. Since row `4` contains two non-NaN elements, we do not increment the count. Rows `0` and `1` contain two NaN's, so the count is also not updated.

Comment: Can you please explain the requirement clearly in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
df.isnull().sum(axis=1).eq(1).sum()    
# 2
```

1. `.isnull()` Check nulls
2. `.sum(axis=1)` Count nulls by row
3. `.eq(1)` Check number of nulls equal to 1
4. `.sum()` Count rows with exactly one null